# Problem to order a table by specific column in PHP

Tags: php

I'm try to order a MySQL result by a specific column (calculated distance) and but I think that the distance columns is a string because of the order result.
For ex. the table is ordered by distance like that : 0,95 - 1,32 - 1,45 - 100,26 - 2,45...

The distance 100,26 should be at the end of the table.

Could you help me to get the correct order, please ?

Main fonction :

```
<?php
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

        // $stmt->bindParam("titre", $data->titre, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $stmt->execute();
        //$mainCount = $stmt->rowCount();
        $offresData = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        //

        $db = null;


        // Calcul des distances
        $lat1 = 0;
        $lat2 = 0;

        // Position de l'utilisateur ou de la ville à utiliser
        if ($dataArr[1] == "1" || $dataArr[2] == "1") {

            $lat1 = explode("<|>", $dataArr[3])[0];
            $lon1 = explode("<|>", $dataArr[3])[1];
        } else {
            // Position du domicile à utiliser
            $db = getDB();
            $sql = "SELECT latitude, longitude FROM client WHERE id=:id";
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam("id", intval($dataArr[4]), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();

            $user = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

            $lat1 = $user[0]->latitude;
            $lon1 = $user[0]->longitude;
        }

        $index = 0;
        foreach ($offresData as $offer) {

            if ($offer->latCommercant != "" && $offer->longCommercant) {
                $lat2 = $offer->latCommercant;
                $lon2 = $offer->longCommercant;

                $offer->distance = distance_orthonormique($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2);
               // $offer->distance = $index;

                if ($offer->distance > $dataArr[0]) {
                    // Trop loin
                    array_splice($offresData, $index, 1);
                    $index--;
                }
            } else {
                // Sinon pas de distance indiquée
                $offer->distance = null;
            }
            $index++;
        }

        if ($offresData) {
            usort($offresData, "sortByDistance");

            $offresData = json_encode($offresData);
            echo '{"offresData": ' . $offresData . '}';
        } else {
            echo '{"error":{"text":"Pas d\'offres"}}';
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":' . $e->getMessage() . '}}';
    }
```

Distance calcul:

```
function distance_orthonormique($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $precision = 2, $r = 6378.14) {
    $x1 = deg2rad($x1);
    $x2 = deg2rad($x2);
    $y1 = deg2rad($y1);
    $y2 = deg2rad($y2);

    // Calcule des distances entre les deux points.
    $dlat = $x2 - $x1;
    $dlong = $y2 - $y1;

    // On applique la formule.
    $a = sin($dlat / 2) * sin($dlat / 2) + cos($x1) * cos($x2) * sin($dlong / 2) * sin($dlong / 2);
    $c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1 - $a));

    // On récupère la valeur du résutat arrondi avec la précision.
    $d = round($r * $c, $precision);

    $distance = (float) $d;

    // On renvoit la distance en km
    return $distance;
}
```

Order fonction :

```
function sortByDistance($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a->distance, $b->distance);
}
```

Comment: Surely seeing this code: `strcmp($a->distance, $b->distance)` should straight away help you solve your issue...

Answer (score 1):

try rewrite order function

```
function sortByDistance($a, $b) {
    return $a->distance > $b->distance ? 1 : ($a->distance < $b->distance ? -1 : 0);
}
```